# C++ plugin loaded in runtime with static global variable

Tags: c++, plugins, runtime, shared

I have a library loaded in runtime. The library contains const static variable e.g. `std::map` of objects.
I load and unload this library multiple times in runtime using multiple threads.

And GCC thread sanitizer complains that threads have data races regarding this object. E.g. while one thread removes the object, second one creates new one - they conflict with the `std::map`. I wonder if shared library loaded multiple times have the same addresses for global variables, functions?

Have can I make the code thread safe in this case?

Where can I read about it?

Comment: Any shared resource must be protected by a mutex.

Comment: `thread_local` might help for const globals.